# Using multiple bluetooth scanning can affect results?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon

So, I'm using `AltBeacon library` for beacon scanning, but in simuntaneously I'm using my own Bluetooth BLE scanner. The thing that I see is that I get updates from my beacon rarely sometimes. I was starting to think, could it be that the delay could be affected because of two scanners that are working. Below is scan result log:

```
2019-09-18 09:11:42.780 14540-14646/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:11:46.121 14540-14648/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:11:49.459 14540-14649/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:11:51.663 14540-14647/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:11:52.781 14540-14648/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:11:55.988 14540-14651/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 37 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:11:58.353 14540-14646/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:05.019 14540-14651/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:06.134 14540-14645/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:08.366 14540-14647/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:25.054 14540-14645/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:26.177 14540-14648/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:28.400 14540-14648/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:51.753 14540-14649/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:56.058 14540-14646/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 37 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:12:59.407 14540-14649/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 37 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:13:01.774 14540-14647/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 196 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:13:02.897 14540-14647/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
2019-09-18 09:13:16.237 14540-14648/com.ai.night I/BeaconManager: Beacon recognized! Minor ID: 38 recognized!
```

It's easy to see that first beacons are found with 3-4 sec interval and that's fine, but then it can take up to 15-30 secs. What could possible cause this?

Comment: Please show your code.  It two scanners are causing the delay, it is likely the implementation specifics.  Threading issues may cause this.

Comment: @davidgyoung I'll add additional notes that I discovered. There are some cases when phone cannot scan specific beacon. Not only my application, but also "Blutetooth scanner", which makes me think that there's some kind of bluetooth stack cache that can get full which causes losing the track of beacon. Have you ever had an experience with this?

Comment: Again, I suspect the problem may be threading.  If one of the threads processing scans gets blocked periodically scan results will slow down.